# Drupal 7 not working with Varnish 3

Tags: caching, drupal, varnish

im trying to get Varnish and Drupal work together. Im using the Drupal-Varnish-Module and i see that the server can be reached over the modules admin panel. I also put the necessary lines of code in my settings.php

```
$conf['cache_backends'] = array('sites/all/modules/varnish/varnish.cache.inc');
$conf['cache_class_cache_page'] = 'VarnishCache';
$conf['page_cache_invoke_hooks'] = FALSE;
```

But still no varnish-caching takes place as i can see in with the shell-command "varnishstat" and also via http://www.isvarnishworking.com

Any idea what the problem could be? Im thankful for any hints!

Regards,
Fab

Comment: Is Varnish setup and working properly? Are you getting Varnish headers in your pages?

Comment: Fot the pity - NO! When i check my site on http://www.isvarnishworking.com i receive a "NOPE!". Any ideas what the problem could be then?
Do i need to activate or deactivate the standard DRUPAL caching for anonymous users?